# Halfing an array, populating it, and then rehalving it

Tags: java, arrays

I have an algorithm I'm trying to write that is supposed to take an array, divide it in half and fill one half with 0s, divide the remainder of the array in half and fill half of that with 1s and so forth until all elements are filled.  An array of 8 characters would look like [0 0 0 0 1 1 2 3].  I've been doing numerous things to write the code for this but always either end up in an endless loop or end up with a null pointer exception being thrown.  My code is below.  Any pointers?

```
public Integer[] generateTestDataHalfs(int size)
    {
        //Generate the array
        Integer[] randHalfs = new Integer[size];

        //Use an integer to store the location of the array
        int arrPlace;
        int currNum = 0;
        int arrStart = 0;       //For the first iteration, start of the array

        //Half the size and set arrPlace to size + 1
        size /= 2;
        arrPlace = size + 1;

        //Use a while loop to populate the array
        while (size > 1)
        {
            //Populate part of the array
            for (int x = arrStart; x == size; x++)
            {
                randHalfs[x] = currNum;
            }

            //Increment the number
            currNum++;

            //Set it to the next part of the array
            size = randHalfs.length - arrPlace;
            size /= 2;
            arrPlace = size + 1;
            arrStart = arrPlace;
        }

        //Return the new array
        return randHalfs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see with your code is the `for` loop: the terminating condition `x == size` will evaluate to `false` (and immediately terminate the loop) unless `size == arrStart`. You don't want that, since it would mean that part of the array would not be filled. A second problem is that if `size == 1`, you won't initialize anything in the (sub)array, which is also wrong. I can't explain the infinite loop, but there may be array lengths where `size` doesn't change values each time through the `while` loop. You can diagnose such cases by stepping through with a debugger or logging your variable values each time through the loop.

In any event, your code can be considerably simplified. My version looks like this:

```
public Integer[] generateTestDataHalfs(int size) {
    Integer [] result = new Integer[size];
    Integer fillValue = 0;
    int start = 0;
    while (start < size) {
        int fillLength = (size - start) / 2;
        // check for final element
        if (fillLength == 0) {
            // fill final element
            fillLength = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < fillLength; i++) {
            result[start + i] = fillValue;
        }
        fillValue++;
        start += fillLength;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You didn't specify what happens when the array length is not a power of 2 (so some of the sub-arrays don't split into equal halves). In the above, I've assumed that the first half should be shorter. If you want the second half to be shorter, just change the line that initializes `fillLength` to:

```
int fillLength = (size + 1 - start) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I tested with size value as integers 0-11. I cleaned up your logic. There is definitely scope to clean this up further. I would like to leave this as an exercise for you.

```
package com.ankur.javacode;

public class DivideArrayHalf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DivideArrayHalf obj = new DivideArrayHalf();

        for(int i: obj.generateTestDataHalfs(0)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public Integer[] generateTestDataHalfs(int size)
    {

        if (size == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        //Generate the array
        Integer[] randHalfs = new Integer[size];

        //Use an integer to store the location of the array
        int currNum = 0;
        int arrStart = 0;
        int arrEnd = 0;
        int tofill = 0;

        tofill = size / 2;
        size = size - tofill;
        arrStart = arrEnd;
        arrEnd = arrStart + tofill;

        //Use a while loop to populate the array
        while (arrStart != arrEnd)
        {

            //Populate part of the array
            for (int x = arrStart; x < arrEnd; x++)
            {
                randHalfs[x] = currNum;
            }

            //Increment the number
            currNum++;
            tofill = size/2;
            size = size - tofill;
            arrStart = arrEnd;
            arrEnd = arrStart + tofill;

        }

        randHalfs[arrEnd] = currNum;

        //Return the new array
        return randHalfs;
    }

}
```